# Creating a function that repeatedly draws from a uniform random variable 10000x and calculating the sample mean and variance for each draw (R)

Tags: loops, statistics, sample, uniform-distribution

[Question at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5tfZ.png)

Hello, I am relatively new to R. I have taken about 2 months of courses, but I have not really actually applied my skills regularly. Fortunately, I am taking a stats course that is pushing me to do just (I am so excited about it).

Anyways, I would like to know the different ways one would approach this. Here is what I have so far(not much):

`z <- runif(n = 100, min= 0, max = 1)` `mean(z)`

I know it is not much, but I do suspect that there are several ways to do this. The way I think it can be done efficiently is by running a for-loop. For example

`times <- 10000`

`for (i in 1:times){runif(n=100, min = 0, max =1)}`

*I KNOW* this may not be even close to correct, which why I ask here. Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

It is important that I am mainly referring to part b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood well what you are trying to do, but using a loop seems good to me.

If you want to get the mean & variance of each of your 10000 samples, then this should work :

```
mean_and_variance <- function(times)
{
    res <- matrix(rep(0,times*2), nrow = times, ncol = 2)
    for (i in 1:times)
    {
        z <- runif(n=100, min = 0, max =1)
        res[i,] <- c(mean(z),var(z))
    }
    colnames(res) <- c("mean", "variance")
    return(res)
}
```

`res` is a matrix of dimension times*2. each row corresponds to the couple (mean,variance) for the sample generated in the loop.

if I didn't understand well your question feel free to tell me.

best regards